# Symfony set the values for form that already created as a formtype

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have created a form type like below

```
/**
 * Class CreatePosFormType.
 */
class CreatePosFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name', TextType::class, [
            'required' => true,
            'constraints' => [new NotBlank()],
        ]);
        $builder->add('identifier', TextType::class, [
            'required' => true,
            'constraints' => [new NotBlank()],
        ]);
        $builder->add('description', TextType::class, [
            'required' => false,
        ]);
        $location = $builder->create('location', LocationFormType::class, [
            'constraints' => [new NotBlank(), new Valid()],
        ]);
        $location->addModelTransformer(new LocationDataTransformer());
        $builder->add($location);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Pos::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

In my controller I have get the form and send the request to the form as below:

```
$form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamed('pos', CreatePosFormType::class);
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

But I need instead of sending the request to the form get the data from the request and set the values for individually I have tried like below:

> $form->get('name')->setData('john');

But It's not setting the form field value.

If I set the values to form by above the below error occures

> {
>       "form": {
>           "children": {
>               "name": {},
>               "identifier": {},
>               "description": {},
>               "location": {},
>           }
>       },
>       "errors": [] }

Comment: Take a look at this http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#handling-form-submissions

Comment: What Symfony version?

Comment: I am using symfony 3.2

Answer (score 1):

You can send the mapped class to the form itself. Like this:

```
public function createPost(Request $request)
{
    $pos = new Pos();
    $pos->setName('John');
    $form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamed('pos', CreatePosFormType::class, $pos);

}
```

You can also send in data through the options. Like this:

```
public function createPost(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamed('pos', CreatePosFormType::class, null, ['yourVariable' => $yourVariable]);

}
```

And in the form class you would catch that in your options.

```
 class CreatePosFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
         $yourVariable = $options['yourVariable'];
         //do stuff with your variable
     }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Pos::class,
            'yourVariable' => null,
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: But my Pos Class doesn't have some variables that in the Form. It uses event to store it in the database

Comment: Edited my answer to include another option.

Comment: "{
    "form": {
        "children": {
            "firstName": {},
            "lastName": {},
            "active": {},
            "email": {},
            "phone": {},
            "plainPassword": {}
        }
    },
    "errors": []
}" 
I have get this below message how to debug in depth

Comment: That is a different form than the original one. This includes "firstName" etc. which are not in the original form. This is a different error and may be because your entity is linked to the form. 'data_class' => Pos::class is always going to map the form to an entity.

Comment: This is exactly what you need.